# R-devel with sanitizer from rocker

Tags: r, docker, rcpp, r-package, address-sanitizer

I'm trying to install R devel with ASAN USBAN from [rocker](https://github.com/rocker-org/rocker). Following the README I tried:

```
sudo docker run --rm -ti rocker/r-devel-san
```

This took a long time to download but at the end it was ok. Then I installed the [sanitizers](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sanitizers/index.html) package to test R against known errors.

```
install.package("sanitizers")
```

And I tried to get an error

```
> sanitizers::stackAddressSanitize(42)
[1] 24
> sanitizers::heapAddressSanitize(1)
[1] 0
```

I didn't get any error so I guess that the R version I'm running with docker is not built with sanitizer support. Or I simply missed something somewhere. It is my first time with docker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you start `RD` and not `R`.  Then it works for me as expected:

```
> install.packages("sanitizers")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/sanitizers_0.1.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3963 bytes
==================================================
downloaded 3963 bytes

* installing *source* package ‘sanitizers’ ...
** package ‘sanitizers’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
g++ -fsanitize=undefined,bounds-strict -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++98 -I"/usr/local/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -mtune=native  -c heap_address.cpp -o heap_address.o
g++ -fsanitize=undefined,bounds-strict -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++98 -I"/usr/local/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2 -Wall -pedantic -mtune=native  -c stack_address.cpp -o stack_address.o
g++ -fsanitize=undefined,bounds-strict -fno-omit-frame-pointer -std=gnu++98 -shared -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o sanitizers.so heap_address.o stack_address.o -L/usr/local/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-sanitizers/00new/sanitizers/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (sanitizers)

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpqpZ0Zg/downloaded_packages’
> sanitizers::stackAddressSanitize(42)
stack_address.cpp:16:32: runtime error: index 142 out of bounds for type 'int [100]'
stack_address.cpp:16:11: runtime error: load of address 0x7fff11a2da88 with insufficient space for an object of type 'int'
0x7fff11a2da88: note: pointer points here
 ff 7f 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  b0 a1 85 ce d0 55 00 00  e3 b1 cb da ed 7f 00 00  78 88 fa cf
              ^ 
[1] 0
>
```

In short, just as in the `r-devel` containers the non-vanilla version you want is `RD` and not `R` which is a plain vanilla R from the standard binary package.

Comment: How can I start RD instead of R? I mean I run `docker run --rm -ti rocker/r-devel-san` without mentioning anything and it opens an R session (which is not devel btw)

Comment: Append the command you want to run at the end -- I usually say `bash`.  If you give none the default is used and we may inherit `/usr/bin/R` from the underlying container here. So you can also say `docker run --rm -ti rocker/r-devel-san RD`.